# When did Monkeys start making wrenches?

Tags: etymology, history, origin-unknown

Why is the *pipe wrench* often called a [*monkey wrench?*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_wrench)
[image]

From the [Ferris State University Jim Crow Museum](https://www.ferris.edu/HTMLS/news/jimcrow/question/2005/february.htm) website…

> Q: Did Jack Johnson invent the wrench?
>
> A: Jack Johnson, the first Black heavyweight boxing champion, patented a wrench (U.S. patent #1,413,121) on April 18, 1922. His patent was not the first for a wrench. Solymon Merrick of Springfield, Massachusetts, patented the first wrench in 1835. Charles Moncky, a Baltimore mechanic, invented the monkey wrench around 1858. Moncky's wrench was named using a purposeful misspelling of his name.

There appear to be 2 common misconceptions based on faulty internet information.

Supposedly there is a racially based myth that the *monkey wrench* was named after Johnson. However, the name was in use at least 100 years before, and his name only appears tangentially to the topic.

> …suggests that African-American boxer Jack Johnson invented the tool, and the racists of the time added the label “monkey” as a racial epithet. However, neither part of this story is strictly true. (1)

The other would seem to be a continuation of the “Moncky” hoax. (2)

> …Another hoax suggests that a man named Charles Moncky invented the tool. Historians have found no record of a Charles Moncky living in the area at the time it is said, though researchers found multiple Charles Monks. However, none of the possible Charles Monks can be the inventor. All were children when the tool was invented or born after the term “monkey wrench” was already in circulation. (1)

And yet another inventor was credited with the invention…

> The apparent inventor of the monkey wrench is Loring Coes, who invented the tool in 1840 in Worcester, Massachusetts. ***That date is about 37 years after the earliest recorded use of the term “monkey wrench”,** however we know that this time the name stuck to the tool Coes invented, as its design remained in production by various companies for the next 120 years. (1)

…so it appears the term was already in use to describe the “carriage wrench”.

[image]

I thought perhaps it came from the phrase “monkey around”, but I [cannot find any use before 1889 on Ngrams.](http://When%20did%20Monkeys%20start%20making/using%20wrenches?)

And it appears that the “smooth lipped” carriage wrench was called a “monkey wrench” at least 37 years before the invention of the modern day toothed-lip pipe wrench.
Even though Coes gets the credit for the name, it was in use long before.

***So why was it originally called a “monkey wrench” ?***

[(1) Healthy Handy Man](https://healthyhandyman.com/who-invented-the-monkey-wrench/)

[(2) Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_wrench)
(3) Images Wikipedia

Comment: The earliest U.S. newspaper references to "monkey wrench[es]" that an Elephind search turns up involve a hardware store advertisement that appeared repeatedly in the _[Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania] Daily Morning Post_, starting in December 1844.

Comment: ...no doubt a product from Loring Coes (1840) @SvenYargs

Comment: The earliest matches for "monkey wrench" in a British Newspaper Archive search come from the _Chester [Cheshire] Chronicle_ in August 1826. The most descriptive of these is from August 11, 1826, in a summary crime report: "William Darlington, aged fi[fty?], a bricklayer, was charged with stealing a **piece of iron, called a monkey wrench**, the property of [the] Chester Canal Company." It is not obvious that the "piece of iron" that Darlington allegedly stole was what people might call today a "monkey wrench" rather than, say, a pry bar, a gouge, or some other simpler instrument. ...

Comment: ... It may be worth noting that Webster's _An American Dictionary of the English Language_ (1847) offers as the only tool-related definition of _wrench_  "An instrument for screwing or unscrewing iron work, and as one definition of _monkey_ "The weight of a pile driver; i.e., a very heavy mass of iron, which, being on high, descends with great momentum on the head of the pile, and forces it into the earth." The term _monkey-wrench_, with a modern definition, first appears in the _ADEL_ of 1864.

Comment: I always thought it was because, like a monkey on a branch, it was sure to get a tight grip on anything.

Comment: @SvenYargs According to _Healthy Handy Man_ and Wiki, the term as applied to  Coes invention was predated by like 37 years..so put it maybe 1803-4. I just cannot naill that down or confirm it.

Comment: Two similar tools are known as "Engländer" (Wasserpumpenzange) and "Franzose" (similar to the monkey wrenche but the screw is perpendicular to the long axis) in German. English man are derogatorily labled "Insel-affen" (island apes). It's a week comparison and why would English men slur themselves?

Comment: I will note that, probably around 1900, there were a number of wrenches produced (apparently for early automobiles) which resembled monkeys in shape.  Partly this was in jest, I'm sure, but the curled "tails" seemed to serve some useful purpose.

Comment: BTW, I'm pretty sure that this question came up somewhere a year or two ago, though I searched both here and on Skeptics and couldn't find it.

Comment: There seems to be a bit of a trend of naming wrenches for other nationalities (not that I’m suggesting ‘monkey’ is a nationality!). The German and Danish terms for the monkey wrench is _Engländer_ ‘Englander’ and _engelsknøgle_ ‘English key/wrench’, while the adjustable spanner in Danish and Spanish is _svensknøgle_ ‘Swedish key’ and either _llave inglesa_ ‘English key’ or _llave francesa_ ‘French key’. The [Swedish Wikipedia article](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skiftnyckel) has a good overview over who calls them by which country (if you can read Swedish).

Comment: @HotLicks There were a couple of Qs about "throwing a monkey wrench in the works", but that was  all I saw when I did an initial search.

Comment: @SvenYargs There was also another trend, going back  200 years or so, that Syphilis was named after the the adjoining country/enemy. i.e. "the French disease", the Greek disease", "the Korean disease", etc. So I read somewhere.

Comment: @SvenYargs Surprised about the British connection, because generally in modern Britain we don't use the word "wrench" much. Here they are "spanners". The Japanese call theirs "supanners", and think it is a Japanese word. The ones illustrated are in Britain "adjustable spanners".

Answer (score 5):

Etymonline has an interesting suggestion on its possible origin::

> ***[Monkey](https://www.etymonline.com/word/monkey-wrench)*** was used in 19c. especially by sailors, as a modifier for various types of small equipment made for specific work (monkey-block, monkey-boat, monkey-spar, etc.), and the same notion probably is behind the name of the tool.

[WWW](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-mon5.htm) has  citations from early 19th century:

> In 1973, E Surrey Dane published a book with the snappy title Peter Stubs and the Lancashire Hand Tool Industry, which includes ***a reference dated 1807 to a firm supplying “Screw plates, lathes, clock engines ... monkey wrenches, taps.***” The entry in the online Oxford English Dictionary includes this but with a question mark before the date, which means that their editors have yet to verify it beyond doubt.
>
> There’s then a gap until it turns up in Francis Whishaw’s The Railways of Great Britain and Ireland, dated 1840; , in which he quotes Orders to Enginemen and Firemen issued by the Liverpool and Manchester Railway, ***dated 1837; this includes a list of tools that must be kept in a locomotive cab, including “one large and one small monkey wrench”.***

Comment: Yes I saw that (first stop). I think there should be a primary source for the Surrey Dane citation for it to actually qualify. Right now it appears the date in in doubt.

Comment: @Cascabel,  it is on page 219: https://books.google.it/books?redir_esc=y&hl=it&id=Gm4oAQAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=monkey+wrenches

Comment: Yes but what I am asking for is a primary source: that appears to self-referencing. <<The entry in the online Oxford English Dictionary includes this but with a question mark before the date, which means that their editors have yet to verify it beyond doubt. >>

Comment: See the wonderful phrase "[Freeze the balls off a brass monkey](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-brass-monkey/)"

Answer (score 2):

A wrench is called a *key* "Schlüssel" (viz. *schließen, Schloss*); French mont- appears in *Montage* (cp. *to mount*). Thus it may be a *mont-key* (the *t* is silent by the way; What's the french equivalent, mont-cleve?), and the other terms noted by etymonline following from reinterpretation as "monkey" in jest.

PS: On second thought, consider the machanism of the thing. I want to say it may use a pin hole mechanism to fix the height, thus making another connection to *key*, but I'd want to connect *mount*, as long as *key* is already explained to satisfaction. There are different mechanisms, a screw or, as depicted above. Looking longer at the mechanism, I could see how the head *climbs* up (cp *cleve* again, now for a mondegreen).

Comment: The idea that it comes from *something-key* is pretty clever. I don't think *mont* as the first word makes much sense ... isn't it much more likely to be an English word?

Comment: mount, mont, what's the big difference. Or do you have something different in mind?

Answer (score 0):

The term was used in 19c. especially by sailors, as a modifier for various types of small equipment made for [specific work](https://www.wykop.p) (monkey-block, monkey-boat, monkey-spar, etc.), and the same notion probably is behind the name of the tool.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU. Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and consider how you might [improve your answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). As it stands, this sounds like opinion; can you cite sources? Your link is bad.

Answer (score 0):

was used in 19c. especially by sailors, as a modifier for various types of small equipment made for specific work (monkey-block, monkey-boat, monkey-spar, etc.), and the same notion probably is behind the name of the tool.[enter link description here](https://www.wykop.p)

Comment: You should edit your original answer rather than creating a new one (and the link it still bad).